# My application stealing focus

Tags: c++, winapi, focus

Im developing an application and use FlashWindowEx to flash the update window however it always manages to steal focus from full screen applications like games and such.

This is not what i want and is very annoying. Is there any way to work out whats causing it to steal focus (tried commenting out FlashWindowEx but it still did) or a way to tell it not to steal focus.

This happens on all versions of windows (including 7) and the game is launched seperatly to the application.

Comment: The article "[Get user attention without stealing focus](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4889181/get-user-attention-without-stealing-focus)" might be relevant.

Comment: Your application is getting **more** attention and you don't want that because it's *bothering* the user? Wow, maybe there's hope for us, yet.

Answer (score 2):

Check out the WS_EX_NOACTIVATE window style perhaps?